# How to find specific class in type hierarchy in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I only know that by using quick hierarchy view (ctrl + T) I can then write class name `*MyClass` and find it. But I can't find how to do that in type hierarchy view, is it possible?

Eclipse version: Indigo service release 2.

Comment: Why don't you just use ctrl+T then?

Comment: because it opens in pop-up and can be accidentally closed, also it don't display methods.

Comment: I tried typing in the type hierarchy view and it is working fine. What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: It's only working when you type the whole name of the type, you can't use asterisk.

Comment: Okay. AFAIK it is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just click in `Type hierarchy view` (comes when pressed F4) and then start typing. It is working fine for me.
However wildcard searches doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: I just think that it's weird that in the view that is intended specifically for class hierarchy view you can't do what is possible from quick hierarchy view (find class in hierarchy using asterisk), so I thought that maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is that:

- Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+H
- Menu: Navigate->Open Type In Hierarchy...

This will pop you up a window, in which you can write down the name of the class you want and it will then open the Hierarchy view with it.